# Postgresql to pivot

Tags: postgresql, crosstab

I have a requirement like below in postgresql.

```
ID       URL  
1     www.google.com  
1     www.yahoo.com 
1     www.hotmail.com
```

I want the output to be like

```
ID       URL1           URL2          URL3  
1     www.google.com  www.yahoo.com   www.hotmail.com
```

I tried crosstab and I am getting an error SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function crosstab(unknown) does not exist in Metabase and dbeaver. Can someone help with a SQL.

```
select id, case when rn = 1 then url end url1 , 
case when rn = 2 then url end url2
from (
SELECT  *, row_number() over (partition by id) rn
FROM table1 
where url is not null)start1
```

but its not as expected.

Comment: You need to [install](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createextension.html) the [tablefunc extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tablefunc.html)